# Kafka Avro serialize/deserialize into concrete type using schema registry failing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I can't seem to be able to consume messages in their concrete avro implementation, I get the following exception:

```
class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to class my.package.MyConcreteClass
```

Here is the code (I use `Spring Boot`)

**MyProducer.java**

```
private final KafkaTemplate<String, MyConcreteClass> kafkaTemplate;

public PositionProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, MyConcreteClass> kafkaTemplate) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
}

public void sendMessage(MyConcreteClass myConcreteClass) {
    this.kafkaTemplate.send(topic, myConcreteClass);
}
```

**MyConsumer.java**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${consumer.topic.name}'}", groupId = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}'}")
public void listen(MyConcreteClass incomingMsg) {
    //handle
}
```

Note that if I change everything to `GenericRecord`, the deserialization works properly, so I know all config (not pasted) is configured correctly.

Also maybe important to note that I didn't register the schema myself, and instead let my client code do it for me.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

**Config:**

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, MyConcreteClass> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MyConcreteClass needs to extend SpecificRecord

You can use the Avro maven plugin to generate it from a schema

Then you must configure the serializer to know you want to use specific records

`props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true") ;`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have gotten past the original exception, but now I get:
`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class my.package.MyConcreteClass specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.`

It's trying to look in `my.package` which is in the producer application

Comment: You need to externalize your schemas from both applications into an external dependency

Comment: would you able to point me in the right direction for best practices concerning that?

Comment: I don't have links. Try researching Maven or Gradle multimodule projects and setup a private JAR repository to share between your Java projects

Answer (score 1):

In addition to OneCricketeer's answer, I encountered another java.lang.ClassCastException after setting the specific avro reader config. It was `nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class my.package.Envelope cannot be cast to class my.package.Envelope (my.package.Envelope is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; my.package.Envelope is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @3be312bd);` It seems like spring boot devtools wrapped the class in it's reloader module causing jvm thought that's a different class.

I removed the spring boot devtools in pom and it finally worked as expected now.

```
<!-- Remove this from pom.xml -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey! It so happen that I just solved my problem doing exactly this! Do you happen to know why commenting out this dependency makes it work?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting blocked by the same issue as you. Thing is that the `KafkaAvroDeserializer` was deserializing the message as `GenericData$Record` so then spring kafka is searching the class annotated with `@KafkaListener` to have `@KafkaHandler` methods with a parameter of this type.

You'll need to add this property to your spring kafka configuration so the deserializer can return directly the `SpecificRecord` classes that you previously need to generate with the avro plugin:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      specific.avro.reader: true
```

Then your consumer may be like this

```java
@KafkaListener(...)
public void consumeCreation(MyAvroGeneratedClass specificRecord) {
    log.info("Consuming record: {}", specificRecord);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to customize your consumer configuration.
The ContentDeserializer needs to be an KafkaAvroDeserializer with a reference to your schema registry.

Comment: The question never mentioned ContentDeserializer